Handling Multi-Zone UTM to Lat/Lon/Alt Conversions for Continuous Route Mapping in MATLAB
I’m working on a project where I convert geographic coordinates (latitude, longitude, altitude) to UTM coordinates (zone, east, north, altitude) for calculating azimuth and elevation. However, I’m facing a significant challenge because my map spans multiple UTM zones, and as points cross these zone boundaries, the UTM coordinates become inconsistent. This creates discontinuities when I try to map a continuous route, especially for longer paths that cover large geographic areas. My workflow involves:
1.  Converting lat, lon, alt to UTM (east, north, zone, altitude).
2.  Performing calculations in UTM coordinates for azimuth and elevation.
3.  Converting the results back to lat, lon, alt to visualize and analyze the path.

The primary issue is handling points across different UTM zones without causing jumps in coordinates due to zone changes. I’ve tried different methods but can’t achieve smooth transitions between zones. I’d appreciate any advice on managing multi-zone UTM conversions in MATLAB, especially if anyone has experience with similar mapping projects or the MATLAB Mapping Toolbox.
To handle azimuth and elevation calculations accurately for my project, I convert geographic coordinates (latitude, longitude, altitude) to UTM coordinates. The calculations work well within a single UTM zone, but I encounter issues when my points cross zone boundaries. Specifically, the east and north values can change significantly at the boundary, causing discontinuities in what should be a smooth route. My goal is to visualize a continuous path on a map, regardless of zone changes, but the abrupt shifts in UTM coordinates make this difficult.

I try to direct Lat/Lon Calculations: I attempted to bypass the issue by performing calculations directly on latitude/longitude coordinates instead of UTM. While this avoids zone boundary issues, my azimuth and elevation calculations are less accurate because UTM-based calculations were designed to be more precise for short-distance measurements.

% List of geographic coordinates (lat, lon) that cross at least two UTM zones
latitudes = [40.0, 40.5, 41.0, 41.5, 42.0];
longitudes = [-75.0, -74.5, -74.0, -73.5, -73.0];

% Initialize arrays for UTM coordinates and UTM zone names
utmZones = cell(size(latitudes));
eastings = zeros(size(latitudes));
northings = zeros(size(latitudes));

% Convert geographic coordinates to UTM
for i = 1:length(latitudes)
    [eastings(i), northings(i), utmZones{i}] = deg2utm(latitudes(i), longitudes(i));
end

% Display UTM coordinates and their respective zones
disp('UTM Coordinates and Zones:');
disp(table(latitudes', longitudes', eastings', northings', utmZones'));

% Plot UTM coordinates with color-coding for different UTM zones
figure;
hold on;

% Define colors for different zones for better visual distinction
colors = lines(numel(unique(utmZones))); 

for i = 1:length(latitudes)
    zoneIndex = find(strcmp(utmZones, utmZones{i}));
    scatter(eastings(i), northings(i), 100, 'filled', 'MarkerFaceColor', colors(zoneIndex, :), 'DisplayName', utmZones{i});
end

title('UTM Coordinates Across Multiple Zones');
xlabel('Easting (m)');
ylabel('Northing (m)');
grid on;
legend('show');
hold off;

% Convert UTM back to geographic coordinates
latitudes_back = zeros(size(latitudes));
longitudes_back = zeros(size(longitudes));

for i = 1:length(eastings)
    [latitudes_back(i), longitudes_back(i)] = utm2deg(eastings(i), northings(i), utmZones{i});
end

% Display converted geographic coordinates
disp('Converted Back to Geographic Coordinates:');
disp(table(latitudes', longitudes', latitudes_back', longitudes_back'));

% Visualize the original and converted back coordinates on a map
figure;
hold on;
scatter(longitudes, latitudes, 100, 'filled', 'r', 'DisplayName', 'Original Coordinates');
scatter(longitudes_back, latitudes_back, 100, 'filled', 'b', 'DisplayName', 'Converted Back Coordinates');
title('Comparison of Original and Converted Back Coordinates');
xlabel('Longitude');
ylabel('Latitude');
legend;
grid on;
hold off;

